# Как все-таки работает кэширование? Как убить запросы статики из сервера?

Tags: apache, nginx, кэширование, php

Как закэшировать например css файл так, что бы браузер больше никогда его не запрашивал (не создавал запрос к серверу).

Написал я в apache2:
    Header set "Expires" "Mon, 28 Jul 2050 23:30:00 GMT"
    Header set "Cache-Control" "max-age=315360000"

И не пойму как оно работает. В firefox при переходе между страницами убивает запросы на css. А вот если нажать f5 то снова их создает(запросы).

Открываю гугл хром, и он мне пишет, что запросы все таки прошли и не были убиты. Хотя тут же firefox пишет обратное.

Короч помогите разобраться пожалуйста.
Скрины прилагаю)
[Скрин firefox](http://i58.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0328/89/85d7d8f4256e4d76290457151c926589.jpg)

[Скрин гугл хрома](http://i58.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0328/b9/3858a5b22d0ff0546da2ffb07b02e1b9.jpg)

Comment: Когда сервер отдает файлы с заголовком кэша, это означает не то, что браузер обязан в следующий раз запросить его не ранее такого-то времени, а то, что он *может* использовать скачанную версию до такого-то времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В повторном ответе у вас заголовки от сервера 304 Not modified - файл не изменился, можно юзать кешированную версию, сам файл не передается от сервера клиенту.

Comment: Смысл в том, что бы вообще прибить запрос к серверу. То, что он не передается, это хорошо, было бы лучше, что бы вообще ничего не запрашивал.

Comment: Когда нажимаешь F5, браузер считает, что ты хочешь реально обновить все, и посылает запрос естественно, на что в ответ получает, что мол изменений нету. Если же загружать страницу безе F5, а простым открытием, то и запросов не будет.

Comment: @MatthewPatell, если очень хочется, чтобы браузер (не очень старый) вообще не делал запрос к ресурсам, можно воспользоваться кэшированием через [манифест][1].

 [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/html/html/manifest

Comment: Спасибо) Почему тогда firefox при переходе между страницами не делает запросов, а хром все-таки делает? (см. скрины.)

Comment: По вашему скриншоту, хром не делает запроса, там же явно написано "(from cache)"

Comment: Версионирование же работать будет, если через манифест кэширование делать?

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас Nginx, то нужно просто использовать [expires max](http://highload.com.ua/post/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+Cache-control+%D0%B2+Nginx%3F). Кстати при нажатии F5 Хром например игнорирует кеш и повторно отправляет запросы на статику. И кеш будет сохраняться для каждого браузера отдельно. В [PHP включить кеш](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+Cache-control+%D0%B2+PHP) можно так:

```
<?
header("Cache-control: public");
header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + 60*60*24) . " GMT");
```